# Cannot create activex component vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, wcf

I am new to vb, c# ...

I have a vb.net library which creates an active X component (like excel).

When i use the library with my WPF application it works fine. But when I add this library to a windows service project, it throws exception "ActiveX component can't create object or return reference to this object (Error 429)".

I do not understand what is the problem. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly you're doing? Are you working with office applications?

Comment: @AshishSrivastava: Not office application, but a third part application.

Comment: Did you confuse WPF with WCF?

Comment: Check this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa231060(v=vs.60).aspx

Comment: @Rabban: No, with WPF it works fine. With WCF (windows service) application, using interface i tried to call same function in the library, and caused the exception.

Comment: @AshishSrivastava: I read this already, and have doubt only with license. I run the application with a license. But I fear if I need a different license (like server license) to use it with WCF.

Comment: How to check if i need any additional license..